# RBF neural network parameters size

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to define a function approximation by RBF neural network in MATLAB.

RBF needs there parameters as "unit centers", "sigma" and "weight". I have a dataset by 1000 records and 10 features.

first question: these three parameters should be in an array format? or can be in matrix format?

second question: I defined "unit centers" by k-means clustering over dataset. This is three cluster centers.
For "sigma" and "weight" parameters, i should define a matrix same as the "unit centers" size?

unit centers are matrix by 3*10 size. Other two RBF parameters should assign in 3in10 size? Or can i define them in 1in10 or 2in10 size?

Comment: What function in matlab are you trying to use for this purpose?  Is this a regression or classification problem?

Comment: This is a classification problem. I have written my own code not any special function. I applied Gaussian Kernel for classification. I just want to be sure if "centers" are in matrix format, does "width" and "sigma" should be forced in a matrix format? or they are always in an array format?

Answer (score 0):

Centers are of course in the form of a matrix, you have 10 features, you are calculating the centers by distance based on these 10 dimension. and you have more than one centers so it is a matrix of shape: (#centers,#features).

Sigma is just a single number for every center so it is in the shape of: (#centers,1), hence it is a 1D-array

Weights depend on the size of hidden layer(Centers) and with one output neuron it is of the shape: (#centers,1), it is a 1D-array

one last thing to mention here is that, number of your centers is small compare to your input size which is 1000. try 100, 200 or even 500 centers if you did not get good accuracy on test set.